# Looking for OpenSource Cleaning / cache deleting application for Mac

Tags: software-recommendation, hard-drive, macos, open-source

In the times of small SSD harddisks, I was looking for an **open source** software to delete caches and other space wasters like logs, unused application remains and such on Mac OSX, and all over the web people are telling me there's plenty of OSS projects doing exactly that. Sadly, I couldn't even find one of them.

I want to play around with an open source software that does this kind of things. I'd like to know the most complete and if possible documented open source project for hard disk cleaning, if any exists at all.

(Please don't tell me if it's useful to delete caches, that's not the question)

Comment: This maybe helpful http://superuser.com/questions/177206/cleaning-up-mac-os-x/634297#634297

Comment: OnyX is another free tool, but I don't think it's open source :/

Comment: I tell you want you don't want to hear.  There is a reason for caches.  It's to speed up your mac. If you want to clean out your caches, boot in safe mode.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/mac/ccleaner) to delete caches and other things, and it's free

Comment: If this is OpenSource, where is the source?

Comment: It is *not* open source. Cf. https://www.piriform.com/legal/software-license/ccleaner